# External references: Cannot reference memoir labels in other document classes

Tags: cross-referencing, memoir, auxiliary-files

Is there any way to reference `memoir` labels in other document classes?

I've written my thesis in `memoir` and is now preparing slides in `beamer`, in which I want to reference elements in the thesis (section names and page numbers). Problem is, that `memoir` writes labels to the aux-file using memoir-only macros, in this case `\M@TitleReference`, which `beamer` cannot parse.

Minimal example: Given the two files `thesis.tex`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\label{cha:test}

\end{document}
```

and `talk.tex`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\externaldocument{thesis}

\begin{document}
Ref: \ref{cha:test}
\end{document}
```

I expect talk.pdf to contain the text `Ref: 1`, but it does not. Compiling `thesis.tex` and then `talk.text` will result in the error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> {\M@TitleReference 
                              {1}{Test}}{1}{Test}{chapter.1}{}
l.4
```

The manuals for `memoir` and `beamer` do not mention `xr` or `xr-hyper` and vice versa. Googling hasn't helped me either, hence I am stumped.

Note: Omitting `hyperref` in `thesis.tex` makes no difference and neither does using `xr` instead of `xr-hyper`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `\M@TitleReference` is unknown in `beamer` class and is defined (well, `\let` to `\@firstoftwo`. in `memoir` class. It's definition can be 'stolen' and introduced to the `beamer` document, however, in a `\makeatletter...\makeatother` pair, since there is a `@` character in the macro name.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\let\M@TitleReference\@firstoftwo%
\makeatother
\externaldocument{thesis}

\begin{document}
\ref{cha:test}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great! It seems however, that bad things (TM) happen when calling `\externaldocument{thesis}`, when thesis `\include`s chapters. I've accepted your answer, but other should note this limitation.

Comment: @spet: I can't confirm your 'objection' -- I used a `thesis.tex` which includes chapters with specific labels and could refer to them correctly in the `beamer` document.

Comment: I suspect my usage of other reference related packages are causing some interference, but I do not have the time to investigate. The solution in your answer works, although I have to use `\externaldocument{chapter}` for each chapter file as a workaround.